# What is <> In React JSX?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

Just as the title, what does  mean in React? Like this code below.

```
return (
 <>
   <h1> Just a simple header </h1>
 </>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React fragment https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

it's just a shortened syntax

This:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Equal to this:

```
return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the short syntax of `React.Fragment`. However, be in mind that that it doesn’t support keys or attributes. If you wanna add key or attributes. You should use back the **original syntax**

```
<React.Fragment myOwnProps={...sth} key={...otherThing}>
      <div>...</div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) out

Answer (score 0):

These are shortened syntax for code fragments https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

> ...There is a new, shorter syntax you can use for declaring fragments. It looks like empty tags...